# Как убрать лишнюю запятую в JSON?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет. Мне нужно удалить последнюю запятую из строки. Я нашел regex, который выбирает как раз последнюю запятую, но в python оно, почему-то, убирает все запятые.
`re.sub(r'(,)(?!.*,)', '', str)`
[regex](https://regex101.com/r/bzcWcg/1)

Было:

```
[
            { "key": "admin", "text": "Internal user" },
            { "key": "agent", "text": "Agent" },
            { "key": "corporate_landlord", "text": "Company Landlord" },
            { "key": "private_landlord", "text": "Landlord" },
            { "key": "tenant", "text": "Tenant" },
            { "key": "landlord", "text": "Landlord" },
            { "key": "none", "text": "None" },


        ]
```

Стало:

```
[
            { "key": "admin", "text": "Internal user" }
            { "key": "agent", "text": "Agent" }
            { "key": "corporate_landlord", "text": "Company Landlord" }
            { "key": "private_landlord", "text": "Landlord" }
            { "key": "tenant", "text": "Tenant" }
            { "key": "landlord", "text": "Landlord" }
            { "key": "none", "text": "None" }
        ]
```

Нужно:

```
[
        { "key": "admin", "text": "Internal user" },
        { "key": "agent", "text": "Agent" },
        { "key": "corporate_landlord", "text": "Company Landlord" },
        { "key": "private_landlord", "text": "Landlord" },
        { "key": "tenant", "text": "Tenant" },
        { "key": "landlord", "text": "Landlord" },
        { "key": "none", "text": "None" }


    ]
```

Comment: А что за json? текст для обработки что ли? Так проще заменить `},' (возможно с пробелом) на `,`. Или запятую, после которой идет перевод строки

Comment: Ну, у меня есть js файлики, из которых нужно достать только часть вот в квадратных скобка + удалить несколько свойств. И вот после удаления получается так, что на последней строке остается запятая, а это ошибка. Просто, странно, что на regex101 все выбирается норм, а уже в самом python не работает

Comment: Остается висячая запятая что ли? Но она же уникальна из-за `]`. Почему просто не сделать замену вида `re.sub(r",\s*\]", "]", subject)`?

Comment: Нашел, по сути, дубликат вопроса. [Вот здесь 1 и 2 ответы все решают](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56592689/python-remove-comma-of-last-object-in-a-string-for-valid-json)

Comment: Так-то вообще можно не работать с жсон, как с текстом, а распарсить его, удалить нужные поля и сохранить обратно. А если парсер падает на этой запятой - можно попробовать взять pyjson5, который позволяет и запятую и коменты. Конечно за счет скорости, но это намного надежнее, чем править жсоны как тексты.

Comment: @vitidev, ты своей регуляркой можешь строки попортить. А что касается работы с json как с текстом - часто это самый простой способ сохранить форматирование если этот файл, например, написан программистом вручную.

Comment: @ДимаЭф, неа, они там косячные. По крайней мере, с регулярками.

Comment: Просто нужен парсер, которому не мешает эта запятая) json5 подойдёт

Comment: @vp_arth, если парсить и перезаписывать json, то форматирование испортится же? Или он умеет сохранять?

Comment: Испортится, или улучшится) Это смотря как посмотреть. Я обычно в валидный pretty-json сериализую, не уверен, что есть смысл сохранять исходное форматирование.

Comment: В смысле, нафига тебе его вообще пересохранять, если это файл с ручным редактированием и авторским форматированием?  Парсишь и используешь, что напарсил)

Comment: @vp_arth, ну если какую-то утилиту по добавлению чего-нибудь себе делаешь, то вполне может быть надо дописывать в файлы с ручным форматированием. Причём, ещё и вставить в том же форматировании. Я всегда регулярками такое делаю, впрочем, обычно, под конкретный файл) PS: Звать забываешь - я ж не автор ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[playground](https://tio.run/##lZFRS8MwFIXf@ysuF6HJKAP1bTCG6IsgPvnWZJLZsHVrb8pNJhbb314bRegme/AtOfc7J@Gepg07R7fDUNaN4wBsk2TvYQmMiHkC8Al4sC0uAE1Rl4QZYLAfIQqPFCyTqeDoLSP02Sm@tRSm@N23cI69OR4fNsG@VoaKynEx9dy7ujHUwtPv7NzecPl@yXzRFCyZ07@9/Cjn4L9SfR12U/DBkUoDbNiaAyjsM9AKoSTwgUvaeqX@RJAjO414jvcI6bGNWIyjWI2d@@NGcJoJ5Wditcx1r7srKTuBYrXI12Oy7pSayxl2@Rq1TDPgVF2rm/Gw9zJJxrVREDFPDsMX)

```
import re

js = r"""[
  { "key": "admin", "text": "Internal user" },
  { "key": "agent", "text": "Agent" },
  { "key": "corporate_landlord", "text": "Company Landlord" },
  { "key": "private_landlord", "text": "Landlord" },
  { "key": "tenant", "text": "Tenant" },
  { "key": "landlord", "text": "Landlord" },
  { "key": "smth", "text": "Don\'t break \"}, ]\" in strings\\" },
  { "key": "none", "text": "None" },
]"""

json = re.sub(r',(\s*(?=[]}]|$))|("(?:[^\\"]|\\.)*"|[^"])', r'\1\2', js)

print(json)
```

```
[
  { "key": "admin", "text": "Internal user" },
  { "key": "agent", "text": "Agent" },
  { "key": "corporate_landlord", "text": "Company Landlord" },
  { "key": "private_landlord", "text": "Landlord" },
  { "key": "tenant", "text": "Tenant" },
  { "key": "landlord", "text": "Landlord" },
  { "key": "smth", "text": "Don\'t break \"}, ]\" in strings\\" },
  { "key": "none", "text": "None" }
]
```